# Snowflake flatten Avro File

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, avro

We recently received a avro file from an external vendor and we loaded this into snowflake. And vendor also provided below query to read columns in snowflake:

```
SELECT *,COUNT(session_id) AS measure_0
FROM
  TABLE1 session
WHERE
  (EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 AS column_0
    FROM
      UNNEST(session.hits) as hits,
      UNNEST(hits.click) as clicked_text 
    WHERE ((REGEXP_CONTAINS(CAST(clicked_text.text AS STRING), r"(?i)^Activity Report$")))) 
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 AS column_0
      FROM UNNEST(session.hits) as hits
      WHERE ((REGEXP_CONTAINS(CAST(hits.url.domain AS STRING), r"(?i)^wxb2lb\.ww\.com$|^wxb-tablet\.ww\.com$|^wupb-tablet\.wes\.com$|^wu2\.nun\.com$|^hpos\.ter\.net$|^pos2\.ion\.net$|^hposlb\.ncd\.com$|^ihm-out-retail\.wu\.extranet\.sf\.intra\.laposte\.fr$|^ihm-out-retail\.help\.extranet\.sf\.intra\.laposte\.fr$|^ihm-out-retail-pi\.hp\.wu\.extranet\.sf\.intra\.nposte\.fr$|^ihm-out-retail-rmoa\.hp\.lepo\.extranet\.sf\.intra\.laposte\.fr$")))
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS column_0 FROM UNNEST(session.hits) as hits WHERE ((REGEXP_CONTAINS(CAST(hits.url.domain AS STRING), r"(?i)uat|rom"))))
    AND session._PARTITIONTIME = '2024-01-28'
  )
LIMIT
  1000
```

For some reason, UNNEST function is not working here. Can you please suggest whats the mistake here.

```
ERROR:syntax error line 9 at position 27 unexpected 'as'. (line 26)
```

If anyone has flattened avro file in tabular data , can you please let me know the steps / documentation.

Comment: H - can you explain what " UNNEST function is not working" means? Does it give an error (what error message) or does it not return the expected data (what does it return and what did you expect)? Please update your question with this information - don't add it in a comment

Comment: Updated issue with error message

Comment: As far as I’m aware UNNEST is not a valid Snowflake SQL function. You probably need to use FLATTEN but it’s not a like for like replacement for UNNEST, you’d need to re-write parts of the SQL rather than just replace UNNEST with FLATTEN